# passing intent with onClick of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I am fetching id from the database onClick() of the card in recyclerview and passing this id in the next activity where details related to this id should be displayed.  The id I am getting is wrong and hence wrong details are  gettinng displayed. Please help.

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ListInvoice listInvoice = listInvoices.get(position);

    holder.invoice_noText.setText(listInvoice.getInvoice_no());
    Picasso.with(context).load(listInvoice.getLogo()).resize(180,80).into(holder.imageText);
    holder.dateText.setText(listInvoice.getCreated_at());
    holder.cc_codeText.setText(listInvoice.getCc_code());
    holder.nameText.setText(listInvoice.getName());
    holder.test_priceText.setText(listInvoice.getTest_price());
    id = listInvoice.getId();
    holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            context = v.getContext();
           int a = holder.getAdapterPosition();
           passData(a);

        }
    });

}

private void passData(int a) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context,InvoiceDetails.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", ""+id);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

And this is how I am fetching in next activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    loadInvoice(id);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       id = listInvoice.getId();
       passData(id);

    }
});
```

---

```
private void passData(int id) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context,InvoiceDetails.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", ""+id);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: @AparnaMutnalkar Happy to hear that..happy coding..you can accept my answer.

Comment: @AparnaMutnalkar ya its right but some other downvoted it..you can also accept my answer by clicking on tick mark..

Comment: thanx a ton..happy to help you @AparnaMutnalkar

Answer (score 1):

Try this you need to pass id of clicked item of `recyclerview`

```
private void passData(int a) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context,InvoiceDetails.class);
    intent.putInt("id", a);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

GET ID

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
int id = extras.getInt(YOUR_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(context,InvoiceDetails.class);
   intent.putExtra("id", ""+ listInvoice.getId());
   context.startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

**Receiving Data:**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
loadInvoice(id);
```